# Talking some items from the web using Java?

Tags: java, php, web-scraping, speech

I'm trying to build a Java application, which can extract some values from a web application that has been written using PHP.

The web application is a simple online banking system, and the values that will be extracted are the beneficiary account number and the transferred money.

So the Java application will talk these values, thus my issues are:

1. How to extract these values from the web application using
   Java?
2. How to speech these values using Java?

Comment: One '?' indicates a question, whereas 2 or more typically indicate a buffoon.  *"speech these values"*  DYM turn them from text to speech?  That is an ***entirely*** different question to web-scraping, and should be *asked* on a separate question.

Comment: @Mohannad : did you mis spell your name ??? should it be Mohammad ???

Comment: @Hussain, no this is my name, I haven't misspelled it :)

Comment: @Andrew, exactly I wanna turn them from text to speech

Answer (score 1):

for issue 1- I thing you have to learn WEB services to communicate with cross plateform communication
See [THIS](https://www.google.co.in/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=web+services+java+tutorial+for+beginners&oq=web+se&gs_l=hp.3.0.35i39j0l3.1195.2362.0.3546.6.6.0.0.0.1.392.1482.0j3j2j1.6.0...0.0...1c.1.17.psy-ab.qAPogA13mtE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47810305,d.bmk&fp=31b0e87befecb347&biw=1360&bih=599)

for issue 2- Read about [javax.speech.recognition](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-doc/)

Comment: @Mohannad : this is pretty much your answer here